# Couldn't understand why Java and Scala lower bounds behave different

Tags: java, scala, generics

I've very simple example both in java and scala
Java one:

```java
public class LowerBound {

    public void myFunction(List<? super Integer> myList) {
        myList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

```java
public class LowerBoundMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LowerBound lb = new LowerBound();
        List<Integer> myList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList1.add(1);
        myList1.add(2);
        myList1.add(3);

        lb.myFunction(myList1);

        List<Double> myList2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        myList2.add(2.0);
        myList2.add(3.2);

        //lb.myFunction(myList2);
        
    }
}
```

here as I expected lb.myFunction(myList2) gives an error because I'm waiting List<Integer> or supertype of List<Integer>, and List<Double> is not a supertype of Integer

But in Scala

```scala
class AnotherLowerBound {
  def myFunction[T >: List[Int]](input: T) = {
    println(input)
  }
}
```

```scala
object LowerBoundScalaMain extends App{

  val pos1 = new AnotherLowerBound
  val myList: List[Double] = List(2.32,4.31,3.54)
  pos1.myFunction(myList)

}
```

it prints List[Double] without problem?
Is the reason in Scala both List[Double] and List[Integer] are a subtype of AnyRef? Or am I doing some syntax mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Scala and Java have different type systems, they don't have to behave the same way
2. in Java example you used **existential type**, in Scala example you used **parametric type**, so it's already apples vs oranges. You would have to define signature in Java as

   ```
    <T super Integer> void myFunction(List<T> myList)
   ```

   except that is not a valid Java code
3. All data structures (except Array) are **invariant** in Java, so type inference won't be able to figure out least upper bound of two different types. In Scala immutable Lists are **covariant** allowing type inference to find that `List[Int]` and `List[Double]` are both of type `List[AnyVal]`
4. `List[AnyVal]` is the type inferred for the call of generic Scala method. Java is not able to do this (it doesn't allow defining type parameter to be covariant) so it fails for compile when it would have to infer a common supertype of Java's mutable `List[Integer]` and `List[Double]` to pass value as existential type.